# Opening connections to the two mysql databases at the same time

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc

I have a java JDBC program,which opens connection to mysql database and do some operations.

I want to connect to two databases, one in local machine and another
in remote machine.

I am able to connect one at a time, but I want to open both the connections at the same time, at one shot.

This is my java program:

```
public class DatabaseOperations {

    Connection con = null;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    //tring url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.26:3306/time_entries_test";
    String dbName = "time_entries_test";
    String connect1 = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.26:3306/" + dbName + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password + "&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";
    String connect2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dbName + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password + "&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";

    public Connection createConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            //con = DriverManager.getConnection(connect2);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connect2);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Here connect1 and connect2 are two url strings to which I want to open connections.

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: have you already try to use two `Connection` type variables?

Comment: @jigar joshi my question is how can i do that??

Answer (score 1):

You can't have single `con` reference to two database connections.
You definitely need to maintain two different references.

```
Connection con1 = DriverManger.getConnection( connect1 );  
Connection con2 = DriverManger.getConnection( connect2 );
```

No alternative.

---

***Update 1***:

> *how do i return both con1 and con2,so that i can use both there in my method to do operations??*

**Solution 1**: Create multiple methods that returns local and remote connections.

```
public Connection getLocalConnection() {
  ...
  Connection localCon = DriverManger.getConnection( connect1 );  
  ...
  return localCon;
}

public Connection getRemoteConnection() {
  ...
  Connection remoteCon = DriverManger.getConnection( connect2 );  
  ...
  return remoteCon;
}
```

**Solution 2**: If you want to generate both connection on every call and return them, you better use a list object to return..

```
public List<Connection> createConnection() {
  ...
  Connection localCon = DriverManger.getConnection( connect1 );  
  Connection remoteCon = DriverManger.getConnection( connect2 );  
  ...
  List<Connection> connectionsList = new ArrayList<Connection>( 2 );
  connectionsList.add( localCon );
  connectionsList.add( remoteCon );
  ...
  return connectionsList;
}
```

I prefer to use `Solution 1`, because I am not sure every time you will be requiring both connections. At times you may be checking some data in only one database.

Comment: thankx,and should i have to return both con1 and con2 to the method which is calling this connection method??

Comment: @Ravindra how do i use con1 and con2 to do operations with both the databases??

Comment: @joee I suggest you refer to [***Oracle's JAVA - JDBC tutorial***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) to understand database operations using java.

Comment: @Ravindra but i know the operations,my question is i am returning con1,->return con1;.using that con i will do operations,how do i return both con1 and con2,so that i can use both there in my method to do operations??

Comment: @joee Two ways. 1. You have to change return type of the method as a collection of connections created. 2. Define separate methods such as `getLocalConnection`, `getRemoteConnection`.

Comment: @joee Check my updated answer with suggested solutions.

Comment: @Ravindra thankyou very much,after i return that collection in my method how to retrieve and how i will know which one is localconn and which one is remoteconn??

Comment: @Ravindra i mean how to use them in my method where it returns??

Comment: @joee You should be using relevant index to identify local and remote databases. I can give you example here, but seems out of current posting scope.

Comment: @joee `List`s are zero based. `list.add( 0, localCon )` adds `localCon` at `index 0`. And `list.add( 1, remote ..` ... I hope you got it now. Read [*java.util.List API documentation*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).